# Problema con "position:sticky" con antecesor "overflow:hidden" (CSS)

Tags: html, css, web

Buen día.

Tengo problemas con la propiedad sticky. La disposición que tengo es la siguiente:

[image: Disposición de los elementos y sus clases]

```
.A {overflow:hidden;}
.C {height: 500px;}
.D {height: 100px; position: sticky;}
```

Leí en varios blogs que sticky no funciona solo cuando el antecesor directo tiene la propiedad overflow:hidden. En este caso, hay mas de un nivel entre la clase A y D. La clase C tiene definido un height que permite el desplazamiento por dentro pero incluso aunque  fuerce a agregarle la propiedad "overflow: visible", el elemento de clase "D" no se comporta como sticky.

Agradecería un montón que me ayudasen con este tema!

Comment: Buen día, Si no se comporta como sticky es porque no logras que el bloque contenedor  "C" y el borde de abajo pase el tope opuesto, este debe tener la característica de que sea scrollable si no, tomará como referencia el viewport y según tu ejemplo jamás pasara, por otro lado, el padre de tu elemento sticky tiene overflow:hidden; esto tampoco lo hace funcionar asi como overflow:auto; y como tip si esta utilizando flexbox en un padre con align-items:stretch; tampoco funciona el sticky, asi que revisa si tienes esto en el padre.